# Jekyll Collection Output True

Tags: jekyll

I'm using siteleaf for my jekyll site. 
Here's my problem: I created a metadata field called "image" inside siteleaf cms. This will allow the site publisher to add an image. 
Here's a visual - https://ibb.co/kHcHdG

With out an image the users posts won't show on the site. After creating this metadata field and uploading an image, siteleaf will then create an _uploads folder in my jekyll directory, a folder for all images.

Jekyll ignores folders beginning with an underscore, so I have to input this yaml code inside the config file to fix this. Code Below.

```
collections:
  uploads:
title: Uploads
  output: true
posts:
  title: posts
  output: true
```

Inside my _posts folder, I have a markdown file with front matter that looks like this, code below:

```
---
title: popcorn
date: 2017-11-06 15:33:00 Z
image: "/uploads/15023253524_589c7b137f_k-ab220c.jpg"
layout: post
---
```

lorum ipsum.

So far, I followed the right directions, I'm not getting any errors in the console or in jekyll. The posts will not show. I've ran into a wall. I've asked on the jekyll and siteleaf forums, no solution.

Here's a link to the repo - https://github.com/pizzapgh/kevins_site

Help would be appreciated so much, thanks.

Comment: How are you testing your posts? They are being generated fine, everyone but `_posts/2017-10-27-burgers-are-good.markdown` that contains a wrong `layout` (should be `post`)

Comment: I'm testing them on github and local. I've thrown a lot of test post in there out of frustration. The post layout is missing because I simply forgot.

Comment: There is a problem with your `gh-pages` branch, it just contains the unprocessed files but not the `_site` content, try removing `posts` from `collections` in `_config.yml`

Comment: maybe there's a js in the gulpfile that's preventing from pulling images from the uploads folder. I still can't get these images to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, finally!

The solution: Go inside my index file and change the following code:

original code

```
{% if post.img %}
<img src={{ "/assets/img/" | prepend: site.baseurl | append: post.img 
}} alt="{{post.title}}" />
{% if post.img %}
```

new code

```
{% if post.image %}
<img src={{ post.image | prepend: site.baseurl }} alt="{{post.title}}" />
{% if post.image %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for including a link to your repo.

Here's what I did:

```
$ bundle install
$ bundle exec siteleaf serve
```

A few warnings show up in the console, but your site is able to build regardless.

I'm able to access your posts now in the web browser just fine, for example: http://localhost:4000/popcorn/

If you were not expecting this URL pattern, you can change your config file. Right now it says:

```
permalink: ":title/"
```

For info on customizing permalinks see: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/

Comment: Interesting, so when you run it local you're able to see the posts. I wonder why it's not showing on github then.

Comment: Also I pulled the changes down locally, and when I run $ bundle exec siteleaf serve, it says missing gem file

Comment: Before you run the above commands, make sure to change directory to the location of your working folder and Gemfile (e.g. `$ cd /my/folder`)

Comment: If it shows up locally, but not on GitHub, check your repo under Settings > GitHub Pages for errors. You may also want to fix those build warnings.

Comment: Thanks Sky. I'm not getting any build warnings anymore. I had to push an empty  commit to fix. On Nov 3rd GitHub was having increased build errors. Also  I'm pretty sure I was  in the  right directory, but I'll check again, I've made that silly mistake before.

Comment: I've looked inside the directory, I cannot find a gemfile. Running bundle install does not work.

Comment: Where is the gemfile in the directory?

Comment: How were you able to run bundle install? I get "cannot find gemfile" when I run this command.